# SVG system for dynamically coloring paths (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, cordova, svg, sprite, xlink

For a **Cordova** app, I have an SVG map, containing about 30 countries (each country = one path). This map will be used **a lot** throughout my application: sometimes **10x per page**.

Now, I have to be able to **color each country dynamically** for every instance of the map. For example using jQuery:

```
$('svg.map .usa').css('fill', 'blue');
$('svg.map .canada').css('fill', 'green');
...
```

What do you all think is the best (or a good) way to do this?

xlink:href? Inline SVG? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `background-color` use `fill`, and your path will be filled with indicated color.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the css in my question (I have updated it now) :) My question is about how to structure and include the SVG

Comment: Include inline directly into html. By this way you will have more posibilities to color them dynamicly, with css, or with js.